# If I Reduce the Bitmap quality first and then Rescaling its height/width size, is there a difference if I do it the other way around?

Tags: java, android, kotlin, bitmap, compression

Im following the Android Documentary [DocumentaryLink](https://developer.android.com/topic/performance/graphics/load-bitmap) on how to resize Bitmap height/width(Using `BitmapFactory.decodeStream`). And I already know how to compress bitmap quality and byte size in a basic way (Using `ByteArrayOutputStream()`)

But I just wanna know if there is a difference if I Compress Quality first and then Resize Bitmap Width/Height. And if I do it the other way around?

Or is there a better way to do both that I don't know about.

Plus I also notice that when I resize Bitmap Width/Height, the Bitmap Byte size increases. Can anyone explain this to me? Thanks.

Comment: I'll address your final question: a bitmap (and any other image format) is just a representation in bits of each pixel in an image, alongside other information needed. To load this, you must load each pixel data in memory, so you may see a 100kb image, that uses 6 MB of memory? HOW? Turns out, a pixel is not a boolean... (unless the image is pure black and pure white...) each pixel needs more space to represent all the info, color, alpha, etc. All this must go in memory uncompressed (unlike the file)...

Comment: ... so when you resize a Bitmap, even if you make it "smaller" in width/height, when you save this file, you're not saving it using the same compression (PNG, JPEG, etc.) that was used (imagine zipping a file), so you're storing the "semi-raw" pixel data, which obviously takes more space.

Comment: As for your first question, I don't know for sure (would have to try), but it really depends on the image, and perhaps other factors. In fact the decision shouldn't be solely based on "what is the difference". What difference? Speed? Memory Usage during the decode? CPU usage? Battery? It really depends on the image, and what you do with it but measure them yourself (profile the operations!) and decide which one is more efficient.

Comment: Thank you for this! Big help, I'll do it right away :D

Comment: Well, a "way around" is not to do this on a mobile device :) (resize big images and compress them), instead perform this operation on a server or one of the many "services" that would do this for you (for a hefty fee, depending on your traffic). I can name one I used in 2013: https://www.imgix.com/ (it's an example, I have no affiliation with them, but I've used them in the past). Other companies "roll their own". And some others just, like you said, do it locally. The best you can do is make good use of streams, threads, and patience. :)

Comment: Absolutely, no worries. Keep in mind I'm just thinking out loud, I don't have scientific numbers here. You need to figure what uses more CPU/Memory/Battery: Decoding NN bytes of data, or compressing NN bytes of data. If the former is more expensive, you can decode to a smaller size, and then compress; if the later is more expensive, then decode/resize and then compress (less data). You get the idea. But you'll need to measure it yourself, you may even not notice a big difference in most images unless you start to hit some "limit" somewhere.

Comment: Thanks again man, pretty wholesome advise! :D 10/10

Comment: It depends on the actual algorithms involved, but it's generally better to do your (lossy) compression last - keep as much detail and data as possible while you're working on a thing, get the final result, and then compress that. Compressing first means your resizing algorithm has less detail to work with, that kind of thing. (I'm talking generally here - shrinking image dimensions loses data too, so that's the kind of thing you want to do as late as possible)

Comment: But in this case running a compression algorithm isn't going to change the size of your bitmap in memory (which is uncompressed data, *width x height x bit depth*), it just changes the data it contains - and you'll have to compress it again when you write it out to a compressed format, so you're not gaining anything by doing it anytime but the last step! (assuming your compression keeps the same bit-depth etc etc)

Comment: Thanks @cactustictacs ! Ill try this out and Profile this my self to learn more about it.